# How to keep Reactjs API calling function in independent page and call from component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

This code is working fine now I want to move api calling function in to separate page

```
const Login = () => {
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
    .then((result) => {
        let resultEmail = result.email;
        console.log( resultEmail )
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', login: { email } }); 
        console.log(result)
    });
  }
}
```

**===========================**

Please check my code that I added below..
**Problems**

1. Please check any Importing syntax error
2. How can I call login function from login component ?

   *CONSOLE ERROR - TypeError: _services__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.UseApi.login is not a function*

//API services page

```
export const UseApi = () => {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    const login = (email, password) => {
        axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
        .then((result) => {
            let resultEmail = result.email;
            console.log( resultEmail )
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', login: { email } });  
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
}




 //login component
    import UseApi from "./services" ;

    function Login() {
         const handleSubmit = (event) => {
             UseApi.login(email, password) 
         }
    };
```

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: TypeError: _services__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.UseApi.login is not a function

Comment: It seems you are using lower case login instead of Upper case. Can you post your entire service code including the export statement and the component you want to call that function

Comment: Checked with Upper case  USEAPI instead of UseApi but no luck bro @FridayAmeh

Comment: UseApi.Login(email, password)  instead of UseApi.login(email, password)

Comment: I check with UseApi.Login(email, password)  but     ..._3__.USEAPI.Login is not a function

Comment: I will like to see your entire code both can you make a fiddle or code pen?

Comment: OKay , can you access https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-mclaren-8m1r1 , I didnt install anything but you can see my code

Answer (score 0):

edited: services.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../store/globalProvider";

const { dispatch } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const Login = (email, password) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/login", { email: email, password: password })
    .then(result => {
      let resultEmail = result.email;
      console.log(resultEmail);
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", login: { email } }); //dispatch function will pass the action up to BookContext
      console.log(result);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {});

export const UseApi = {
  Login
};
```

let me know if this works for you or not

Comment: ×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app